# OPENCART display prices for each customer group

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I want to let my customer print cart in different customer group prices, so he could print order with retail prices for his customers.
Any example how to show price for specific customer group would be very good.
Thanx!

My website: e-gilius.com
Version 3.0.3.2

Comment: This sounds like custom development that you'll either need a developer for, or knowledge of how to code php & how OpenCart works. Unfortunately this question doesn't show anything that you've done have a look here for [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and if you have an error in your code we'll try and help

Comment: i have this extension

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and simplest way is to use the product discount system, that is, for each product in the discount tab, add the value for each unit or how you sell the product with the specific price for each group of customers you have, so when this When the customer logs in, he will see the price as shown in the discount table.

As an example: I have 2 groups, the standard and the special group
In the "Iphone" product that costs 100 for the standard group, in the discount tab add a discount for the special group, with 1 unit priced at 80.00.
Then when he logs in, he will see the price 80.00.